# File upload in Django

Tags: django, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to get Django to upload a file (keeping it simple, for now), but am having difficulties. Here's all of the relevant code (that I know of).  Perhaps something is wrong with my settings.py? My code is pieces of various answers on Stack Overflow.  I've checked [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs) already.

**When I select a file (~8.5mb file because I saw Django does something funny if it is under 2.5mb) and press Submit, I am brought to the Upload Success page, but can't seem to find my file anywhere in my project directory.**

I am using the development runserver with apache running just for serving images.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/adam/Documents/workspace/sitename/media'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/Library/WebServer/Documents/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'http://10.0.1.15/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)
```

*the static URL is the address of my local apache webserver.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^$', index),
    ('^uploadfile/$', uploadfile),
    ('^uploadsuccess/$', uploadsuccess),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.views.static import serve
    _media_url = settings.MEDIA_URL
    if _media_url.startswith('/'):
        _media_url = _media_url[1:]
        urlpatterns += patterns('',
            (r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % _media_url,
            serve,
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
    del(_media_url, serve)
```

views.py

```
def uploadsuccess(request):
  return render_to_response('uploadsuccess.html', {})

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
  file = forms.FileField()

def uploadfile(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
      handle_uploads(request.FILES['file'])
      form.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
  else:
    form = UploadFileForm()

  return render_to_response('fileupload.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def handle_uploads(file):
  logging.debug("upload_here")
  if file:
    destination = open('/tmp/'+file.name, 'wb+')
    for chunk in file.chunks():
      destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

fileupload.html

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Upload a file</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/uploadsuccess/">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table>
    {% for field in form %}
      {{ field.label_tag }}
      {{ field }}
    {% endfor %} 
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Save"/>
</form>

<body>
</html>
```

uploadsuccess.html

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Upload Successful!</h1>

<body>
</html>
```

Comment: just to verify, did you try looking for it in '/tmp/'+file.name , reason i ask is because you say u can't find it anywhere in your project, and from what i can see the destination is not in your project dir

Comment: This was ONE of my problems, thank you! I was under the impression that /tmp/ was in my project folder not in the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting data to the wrong URL, `change action="/uploadsuccess/"` to `/uploadfile/`.

Comment: This, along with Paul's comment got this working for me.  Thank you!  I now have HttpResponseRedirect('/uploadsuccess/').